# Check which Player got highest Number from Dice

Tags: unity, c#

I am doing a Ludo Game and currently i need to check which Player got the Highest Number from the Dice and the player which has the highest number goes on the starting position. Currently i created this method to check which player got the highest number then the player which has the highest numbers runs the method MovePlayer()

```
public void FirstTurn(){
    player1Steps = GameObject.Find("Player1").GetComponent<LevelManager>().randomNumberSteps;
    player2Steps = GameObject.Find("Player2").GetComponent<LevelManager>().randomNumberSteps;

    if(NetworkManager.MyGamePlayerId == "Player1" && player2Played == true)
    {
        MovePlayer();
    } else if(NetworkManager.MyGamePlayerId == "Player2" && player1Played == true)
    {
        if(player2Steps > player1Steps)
        {
            MovePlayer();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the Photon Cloud Service since this is a multiplayer Game
Thanks

Comment: You are missing the condition for checking if player 1 rolled higher, just by that code player 1 will always move if he rolled after player 2.

Comment: Can you pls show me by the code i provided so i could understand better. Thanks

Comment: You have the condition correctly around the second call to MovePlayer, you need to have it as well for you first MovePlayer, just with switched check if player1 rolled higher

Comment: I didn't understand exactly. Sorry could you show me a snippet. Thanks

Comment: I can see at least 2 issues with the posted code.

 - Your method MovePlayer() has no parameter at all (and we don't know what it's doing) but how should it know if it should move Player1 or Player2? 
 - If the logic is handled inside MovePlayer, you would just need to check if all Players rolled (and since you can play Ludo with 4 people, you should keep that in mind)
 - You should as well consider, what happens when 2 people roll the same highest number.